# How do I add tag to a document that is added dynamically to a template?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I was able to successfully add a document to a template via the API and now I would like to add multiple signature tabs and initial tabs to the document that I just added via the API using the .net c# library.  I created the tabs below and created the envelope and added the document.  Do I have to add the tabs to the document or the template or something else?

```
//Create tabs to be added to do the document.
Tabs tabList = new Tabs()
{
    signHereTabs = new Tab[]
    {
        new Tab()
        {
            documentId = 5,
            pageNumber = 1,
            xPosition = 100,
            yPosition = 150
        }
    },
    initialHereTabs = new Tab[]
    {
    new Tab(){
        documentId = 5,
        pageNumber = 1,
        xPosition = 100,
        yPosition = 150
    }
    }
};

//Create template envolope and its template role

byte[] ips = GetIPS("");

RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = "https://demo.docusign.net";
RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress + "/restapi/v2";
RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = integratorKey;

DocuSign.Integrations.Client.Account account = new DocuSign.Integrations.Client.Account();
account.Email = username;
account.Password = password;
var loginResult = account.Login();


Template template = new Template();

template.TemplateId = templateId;
template.Login = account;


template.EmailSubject = emailSubject;
template.EmailBlurb = emailMessage;
var documents = template.GetDocuments();



var roles = new List<TemplateRole>();


//Handle Primary Client
roles.Add(new TemplateRole
{
    roleName = "Primary Client",
    name = primaryClientName,
    email = primaryClientEmail,

    tabs = new RoleTabs
    {
    textTabs = new RoleTextTab[] {
        new RoleTextTab {
        tabLabel = "FeeEffectiveDate",
        value = effectiveDate
        },
        new RoleTextTab {
        tabLabel = "FeePercentage",
        value = fee
        }
    },
    },
});

if (secondaryClientName.Trim().Length != 0)
{
    roles.Add(new TemplateRole
    {
    roleName = "Secondary Client",
    name = secondaryClientName,
    email = secondaryClientEmail,
    });
}

roles.Add(new TemplateRole
{
    roleName = "President",
    name = presidentName,
    email = presidentEmail
});

roles.Add(new TemplateRole
{
    roleName = "Css",
    name = cssName,
    email = cssEmail
});

template.TemplateRoles = roles.ToArray<TemplateRole>();

template.Status = "created";
var result = template.Create();

//Add the document to the template
bool status = template.AddDocument(ips, "IPS.pdf", 5);

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Now I need to add tabslist created previously to the document.  How do I do this?
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

template.Status = "sent";
result = template.UpdateStatus();
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this after several trial and error.  The Tag/Tabs needs to be added to the template using its AddTabs function.

```
TabCollection ipsTabs = new TabCollection();
ipsTabs.signHereTabs = new List<Tab>();
ipsTabs.signHereTabs.Add(new Tab()
{
    documentId = 5,
    anchorString = "soc1",
    recipientId = "1",
    xPosition = 100,
    yPosition = 150
});
ipsTabs.signHereTabs.Add(new Tab()
{
    documentId = 5,
    anchorString = "soc2",
    recipientId = "2",
    xPosition = 100,
    yPosition = 150
});
ipsTabs.initialHereTabs = new List<Tab>();
ipsTabs.initialHereTabs.Add(new Tab()
{
    documentId = 5,
    anchorString = "ci1",
    recipientId = "1",
    xPosition = -100,
    yPosition = 150
});
ipsTabs.initialHereTabs.Add(new Tab()
{
    documentId = 5,
    anchorString = "ci2",
    recipientId = "2",
    xPosition = -100,
    yPosition = 150
});
var tabstatus = template.AddTabs(ipsTabs);
```

Comment: AFAIK the `AddTabs` method can be used to add tabs to the very first recipient only. Please double-check and see whether the second recipient can see the new tabs as well.